# MySQL syntax error, underscore

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Executing this query

```
INSERT INTO classes(  '_fkUserID',  'date',  'time' ) 
VALUES (

'1',  '2017-07-04',  '8:15'
)
```

gives me the following error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''_fkUserID', 'date', 'time') VALUES ('1', '2017-07-04', '8:15')' at line 1
```

I'm assuming the error has something to do with parsing the underscore, but I can't manage to find a way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
classes('_fkUserID', 'date', 'time')
```

To

```
classes(`_fkUserID`,  `date`,  `time`)
```

Single quotes makes the fields as strings

You don't necessarily need to add the backticks on the column names unless they are [**Reserved Words**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) to the MySql. In your sql statement, `date` and `time` are reserved words, so you must use the backticks on it, which means that it would also work as:

```
classes(_fkUserID, `date`,  `time`)
```

Backticks are Identifier Quote Characters which means that its purpose is to make MySql understand that it should identify whatever is within it as an identifier, in your case a column name.

Comment: If single quotes turns the value into a string, what does the back tick do?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually:

```
INSERT INTO classes(_fkUserID,date,time) 
VALUES (

'1',  '2017-07-04',  '8:15'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the single quotes and use back tick symbol instead (

Comment: If single quotes turns the value into a string, what does the back tick do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402361/what-makes-the-big-difference-between-a-backtick-and-an-apostrophe You could check this StackOverflow post

Comment: More general approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719869/what-is-the-difference-between-the-backtick-and-the-square-bracket-in-sql-statem